# How to prevent mat-select jump to selected value on value selection?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want my mat-select to not jump to the selected value when I click on it.

The problem is that I made optgroups collapsable with my custom toggleExpansion method and when I select an option with a collapsed optgroup, it jumps to the postion of the value before the collapse happened.

I tried set the mat-option height to 0px but it still jumps to the theoretical position of the option

my mat-select code :

```
<mat-form-field >
  <mat-select  [(value)]="tPres" [compareWith]="comparer" (selectionChange)="getSelectedValue($event)" multiple #mySelect >
    <mat-select-trigger>
      {{tPres?.length}} / {{nbPresta}}
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let t of typePrestations">
      <mat-checkbox color="primary" [checked]="isChecked(t)" [indeterminate]="isIndeterminate(t)" (change)="toggleSelection(t, $event)"></mat-checkbox>
      <span (click)="toggleExpansion($event)" class="material-icons"> expand_less </span>
      <mat-optgroup   [label]="t.Code + ' - ' + t.Libelle">
        <mat-option  *ngFor="let y of t.Prestation" [(value)]="y">
          {{y.Libelle}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-optgroup>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

the toggleExpansion method :

```
toggleExpansion(event) {
    if (event.target.innerText == "expand_less") {
      event.target.innerText = "expand_more";
      event.target.nextElementSibling.childNodes.forEach(e => {
        if (e.tagName == "MAT-OPTION") {
          e.style.height = "0px";
        }
      });
    } else {
      event.target.innerText = "expand_less";
      event.target.nextElementSibling.childNodes.forEach(e => {
        if (e.tagName == "MAT-OPTION") {
          e.style.height = "";
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

**EDIT** : I found out a way to do so.

I added a viewchild on my `mat-select` and I overrode its `_onSelect()` method with nothing in `ngOnInit()` :

the method is found in *node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/select.es5.js*

```
@ViewChild('mySelect')   private prestationSelect: MatSelect; 

ngOnInit(){ (<any> this.mySelect)._onSelect = () => {

//The code goes here, I just commented the following line in the method:
//if (isUserInput) { this._keyManager.setActiveItem(option);}
    }
```

Comment: if possible, please create a demo over stakblitz.

Comment: ye I just added this `this.matSelect._onSelect = () => null;` to onInIt ... seems to work :)

Comment: It works but it also remove all the other functionalities of the method.
This means that the state of the selected options won't be emitted when they change.

Answer (score 2):

Using your own answer as a starting point (that you provided in an edit to the question), I came up with the following, which so far appears to work perfectly:

In my HTML I have:

```
<mat-select #selector ...>
```

Then in my class I have:

```
@ViewChild("selector") selector: MatSelect;
...
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   (<any>this.selector).baseonselect = (<any>this.selector)._onSelect;
   (<any>this.selector)._onSelect = (ev, isUserInput) => {
      (<any>this.selector).baseonselect(ev, false);
   };
}
```

I use ngAfterViewInit because this.selector has not yet been initialized when ngInit is called (at least, that was my experience).